# My CSS file connected and working fine with all elements except h1 and a class container-fluid and I am using bootstrap too

Tags: html, css, web-frontend

when I am declaring inline style for class 'container-fluid' .It is working fine but when I shift that style to CSS it doesn't work and I also unable to modify my h1 tag but my title id is working properly which means my CSS is connected properly. Actually I am modifying bootstrap classes.
**This is my main HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TinDog</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

    <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- GOOGLE FONTS -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@1,900&family=Ubuntu:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- FONT-AWESOME -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/78e50f3289.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="title">
      <!-- Nav Bar -->
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="">tindog</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Title -->
        <div class ='row'>
          <div class = "col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <h1>Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg"><i class="fab fa-app-store"></i> Download</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg">
              <i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>
          </div>
          <div class = "col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <img src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

** My Css**

```
#title{
    background-color:#ff4c68;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 3rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #fff;
}

.container-fluid{
    padding:3% 15%;
}

.navbar-brand{
    font-family: 'Ubuntu';
    font-size: 2.3rem;
    line-height-bottom: 5;
}
```

Comment: Use browser inspector tool to check if h1 is being overridden by bootstrap. Provide h1 tag some class then you can easily modify h1 properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I correct it myself by reading some docs, you have to just place your bootstrap link above your custom CSS if you want to play with bootstrap CSS or edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope CSS in `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">`
stylesheet overrides the styles for h1 tag which you have included in styles.css

To resolve this:

1)You can use `!important` to apply your specific styles. It gives high weight to that property and ignores other subsequent rules.

```css
#title{
    background-color:#ff4c68;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 3rem !important;
    line-height: 1.5 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

.container-fluid{
    padding:3% 15%;
}

.navbar-brand{
    font-family: 'Ubuntu';
    font-size: 2.3rem;
    line-height-bottom: 5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TinDog</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

    <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- GOOGLE FONTS -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@1,900&family=Ubuntu:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- FONT-AWESOME -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/78e50f3289.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="title">
      <!-- Nav Bar -->
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="">tindog</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Title -->
        <div class ='row'>
          <div class = "col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <h1 >Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg"><i class="fab fa-app-store"></i> Download</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg">
              <i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>
          </div>
          <div class = "col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <img src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

2)You can also apply your styles with a help of an separate class. Properties in Class gets more priority compared to those in tags.

```css
#title{
    background-color:#ff4c68;
}

.headerclass {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif ;
    font-size: 3rem ;
    line-height: 1.5 ;
    color: #fff ;
}

.container-fluid{
    padding:3% 15%;
}

.navbar-brand{
    font-family: 'Ubuntu';
    font-size: 2.3rem;
    line-height-bottom: 5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TinDog</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

    <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- GOOGLE FONTS -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@1,900&family=Ubuntu:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- FONT-AWESOME -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/78e50f3289.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="title">
      <!-- Nav Bar -->
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="">tindog</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Title -->
        <div class ='row'>
          <div class = "col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <h1 class="headerclass">Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg"><i class="fab fa-app-store"></i> Download</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg">
              <i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>
          </div>
          <div class = "col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <img src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: But then what about the container-fluid class, why the padding doesn't take place??